# Testing for trapped surfaces 

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, einstein-theory

If $M$ is a $n-1$ dimensional Riemannian submanifold in a $1+n$ dimensional space-time manifold $(V,g)$ of pseudo-Riemannian signature $(1,n)$ and $\nabla$ be the Riemann-Christoffel connection on it.

One chooses two future directed null geodesics orthogonal to M say $X^+$ and $X^-$ and defines two rank $2$ tensors $K^+$ and $K^-$ such that their components are,

$K^+ _{ab} = \nabla _a X^+_b$

$K^- _{ab} = \nabla _a X^- _b$

(where $a$ and $b$ run over the indices on $M$)

Let $h_{ab}$ be the components of the induced metric on $M$ from $g$ of $V$. Then one defines the following "null mean curvatures", $\chi ^+$ and $\chi ^-$ along $X^+$ and $X^-$ as,

$\chi ^ + = h^{ab}K^+_{ab}$

$\chi ^ - = h^{ab}K^-_{ab}$

Now apparently $h$ and $g$ can be related as,

$h = g + \frac{1}{2}(X^+ \otimes X^- + X^- \otimes X^+)$

- This is something I am not very clear about. I guess there is some abuse of notation about what is called $h$ since in the two definitions the dimensions of $h$ don't seem to match.

With the above definition one can show that,

$h^{\mu \nu} \nabla _\mu X^+ _\nu = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla _\mu X^+ _\nu$

(where $\mu$ and $\nu$ run over indices of the space-time $V$)

A similar expression holds with $X^-$ and the proof of this crucially needs both the properties that $X$'s are null as well as geodesic. This relates to the notion of ``expansion" of a geodesic congruence and hence shows that null mean curvature is exactly the expansion for the geodesic congruence to which $X$'s would be tangent vectors to.

Now one calls such a $M$ a ``Trapped Surface" if both the null mean curvatures $\chi ^+$ and $\chi ^-$ are negative.

I run into some confusions when I try doing this test on $r=constant$ and $t=constant$ spheres in the Schwarzschild metric,

$ds^2 = -(1-\frac{2M}{r})dt^2 + \frac{dr^2}{(1-\frac{2M}{r})} + r^2(d\theta ^2 + sin^2 \theta d\phi ^2)$

I should get both the null mean curvatures of all spheres inside $r=2M$ to be negative and hence all of them are trapped surfaces. To get this I have to choose the future directed null geodesics orthogonal to the 2-spheres as,

$X^{+/-} = (\frac{+/-1}{(1-\frac{2M}{r})}, -1 , 0, 0)$

- Now I am not very clear as to how to justify that these are both "future directed" inside the event horizon (i.e the surface $r=2M$). (I have some arguments of my own but not very clear) That these are null and orthogonal geodesics to the two spheres is clear.

For the above one gets that $\chi ^{+/-} = -\frac{2}{r}$ and hence justifying that all spheres inside the event horizon are trapped surfaces.

- I would also like to know as to what is the coordinate independent definition for a geodesic to be "future directed" and in how general a space-time can a notion of being "future directed" be imposed globally and continuously.
- Given a general pseudo-Riemannian metric how does one detect the presence or absence of a trapped surface? How does one find such a surface? (The above definition seems to give a test of being trapped if one is given a surface)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding.  However, I believe the expression for the Schwarzschild metric you wrote down in coordinates only holds outside the event horizon (i.e. r>2M).  My guess is if you use coordinates that extend past the event horizon (if I recall correctly an example of these are called advanced and retarded coordinates) then things should work out in a straight forward manner.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of questions you have there. First a bit of nitpick:

- You didn't give enough information to define the null second fundamental forms. Just knowing **a** geodesic is not enough. You need a whole family of them. To be precise, you need $X^\pm$ to be null vector fields along $M$ orthogonal to $TM$, and then you extend them by parallel transport along themselves in the null direction.

For a bit more about the geometry, look at [Galloway's Beijing Lecture Notes](http://www.math.miami.edu/~galloway/) or B. O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry*.

About the relationship between $h$ and $g$: the induced metric on a Riemannian submanifold of a semi-Riemannian manifold can be treated as a projection operator on the total tangent space restricted to over the submanifold. In other words, let $p\in M\subset V$, then because $M$ is Riemannian, you can split $T_pV = T_pM \oplus  (T_pM )^\perp$, then $h$ uniquely lifts from $Sym_2(T_pM)$ to $Sym_2(T_pV)$ by extending trivially in the perpendicular directions. This lift coincides with $g + X^-\otimes X^+ + X^+\otimes X^-$ (if you normalize $g(X^-,X^+) = -1$). (Note, this fixing of normalization is important. You didn't specify it in your question.)

Now, you should get out of the habit of working in Schwarzschild coordinates for the trapped region. That coordinate system is only good for thinking about the exterior of the black hole. Inside the trapped region, the surfaces of constant $r$ are in fact space-like... The picture would be much clearer if you think in terms of Kruskal coordinates.

About "future directed":

- Looks like you are missing a bit of basic causal theory? A space-time is called *time-orientable* if it admits a continuous, non-vanishing time-like vector field $\tau$. For time-orientable space-times, the notion of future and past are well-defined: a causal vector $v$ is said to be future oriented if $g(v,\tau) < 0$, and past-oriented if $g(v,\tau) > 0$. There exists Lorentzian manifolds which are not time-orientable. See any General Relativity textbook for more details and examples (esp. Hawking-Ellis and O'Neill).

Detection of trapped surface:

- Outside of spherical symmetry, where you can detect trapped surfaces by using the metric dual of the one form $dr$, where $r$ is the area-radius (if $dr$ is space-like, then the sphere is non-trapped), there's no general mechanism to detect trapped surfaces, other than a priori knowledge that both of its null mean curvature are negative (as in, this is an open problem). If you restrict to a spatial slice, then there are some work in the Riemannian geometry literature concerning this problem by looking at the Jang equation (I think Marcus Khuri worked on it for a bit, don't know if he is still on it). There are also related work on dynamical horizons and marginally outermost trapped surfaces by Ashtekar, Galloway, Lars Andersson, and others. But if you do find a general way to detect presence of trapped surfaces without local computations, do let me know, because you'd be about a third way there toward solving weak cosmic censorship.

Comment: Also, a geometrically better way of thinking about trapping is to ignore this whole geodesic and null vector field business, and think about the mean curvature vector. The second fundamental form of a submanifold $M\subset V$ measures the failure of $TM$ to be parallel under transport by $\nabla$. Thus the proper way to see the second fundamental form, is that it is a symmetric two tensor on $TM$ that takes value in the normal bundle for $M$. Then taken the $g$ (or the $h$, doesn't matter) trace of this tensor you get a section of the normal bundle over $M$. This is the mean curvature vector.

Comment: If the mean curvature vector is space-like, $M$ is not trapped (near that point). If it is time-like, then it is either trapped (future pointing) or anti-trapped (past pointing, like in a white hole). For spherically symmetric space-times, the mean curvature vector of the symmetry spheres are precisely the metric dual of the one form $dr$ that I wrote above, up to a scalar multiple. For more about the second fundamental form as taking values in the normal bundle, see O'Neill's book. 

Comment: @Willie Thanks for your replies. I am familiar with the understanding of the null second fundamental form as symmetric rank two tensor on the submanifold taking values in the normal bundle. I skipped writing all that and to keep the question short I directly defined the quantities $K^{+/-}_{ab}$. So you are saying that the tensor whose components are $h_{ab}$ (as defined in the question) and the tensor $h$ (as defined in the question) should be thought of as lifts of each other? 

Comment: @ Willie  But then what does this lift tell us? What good it is when it does not lift to the original metric on the full space-time? Is there a way of explicitly writing down the embedding of $M$ in $V$ along which if $g$ is pulled back it precisely gives the metric ${h_{ab}}$ ?  I am familiar with the notion of time-orientability as you defined it. SO I guess you are suggesting that I look in the Kruskal coordinates and identify these symmetry two spheres in those coordinates and also the future directed null geodesics in those coordinates and repeat the calculation? 

Comment: @Willie Thanks for what you called the "nitpicking". It was important. 

Comment: @ Let me try to make the question about "time-orientability" a little more precise. For a space-time is being time-orientable the same as admitting a time-function? (I guess not but can't make it precise) I am aware of the proof that every globally hyperbolic space-time admits a time-function. (I can't see anything ruling out a non-orientable manifold which is globally hyperbolic) Similarly can one ask what is the necessary and sufficient condition for being time-orientable? Does it make sense to ask, when is a black-hole space-time time-orientable or admits a time-function?

Comment: No. Time orientability is **not** the same as admitting a time-function. The latter is much, much stronger than the first. Take Minkowski space and mod it by a unit time translation. It does not admit a time function but the projection of the original $\partial_t$ is still a non-vanishing time-like vector field. If your manifold is already globally hyperbolic, then the metric dual of the exterior derivative of the time function would be a time-orienting vector field, so by definition any globally hyperbolic space-time is time-orientable, but not vice versa.

Comment: Also, to be able to define a black hole, you need time orientation. So the answer to "when is a black-hole space-time time-orientable" is tautologically "always". --- Now about $h$, note that it is only a lift to the "pullback of the TV onto M", not a lift to whole of V. Like I said, it is a projection operator. Write $\tilde{h}$ to be the 1,1 tensor given by $g^{ab}h_{bc}$, then $\tilde{h}$, as a mapping from $TV/M$ to itself is the projection operator of a vector onto $TM$. That is quite a useful thing to have when you need to do submanifold computations. 

Comment: Now, a trivial observation about the projection is that $h^{ab} = \tilde{h}^a_c g^{cd} \tilde{h}^b_d$. This immediately implies that for any object that lives in $T^2M$, its $h$-trace and $g$-trace will be equal (since if you project something in $T^2M\subset T^2V$ by $\tilde{h}$, you get itself back). So in this interpretation, you see that the fact $X$ is null and geodesic is, in fact, not so important, as long as you realize that the second fundamental form is defined, geometrically, as an object in $T^2M$ which extends trivially to $T^2V | M$. 

Comment: @Willie Even outside the closure of the Black-Hole region of a Black-Hole space-time in general global hyperbolicity is not guaranteed but that assumption needs to be put in by hand. (what is called as "asymptotic strong predictability") 



Comment: And yes, I'm suggesting you re-do the computation in Kruskal coordinates. Notice that the light-cone variant of the coordinates is already in double-null form, so not much more work is needed. It will, of course be good for you to understand the Kruskal coordinate also, and not just treat it as a god-given coordinate system. 

Comment: @Anirbit: I didn't say global hyperbolicity. I said **time orientability**. Please read what I said again about what implies what. 

Comment: @Willie Sure! I wasn't contradicting anything! (My browser did not update your replies when I typed that.) I did note your point that definition of Black-Hole needs time-orientability of the space-time and that global hyperbolicity implies time-orientability (and also the existence of a time-function) but not vice-versa. But I wonder if the existence of a time-function implies global hyperbolicity (though the converse is true). Won't the level sets of that automatically give a foliation with Cauchy surfaces? Also is it clear that nakedly singular space-times are not globally hyperbolic? 

Comment: Existence of time function means the space-time is stably causal, which implies that the space-time is strongly causal. So if you add the condition that $J^+(p) \cap J^-(q)$ be compact for every pair of points $p,q$, then you get global hyperbolicity. Another formulation of global hyperbolicity of a domain $D$ is spacetime $V$ is that it admits a time-function $t$ whose level surfaces $\Sigma_t$ all have the same boundary. This condition necessarily implies that $\Sigma_t$ is a Cauchy surface for $D$. Unfortunately this definition is a bit unwieldy for non-compact domains. 

Comment: Let me give two examples: (a) take Minkowski space and remove the origin. It is an open manifold endowed with a time function (b) take the set in 2-D Minkowski space given by $|x-t| < 1$. Again, this is an open manifold, has a time function, but not globally hyperbolic. --- Naked singularities have nothing to do with global hyperbolicity. It, however, has everything to do with asymptotic predictability. You can have a  globally hyperbolic spacetime with a naked singularity (which then cannot be asymptotically predictable); see Christodoulou's scalar field collapse. 

Comment: @Willie Thanks for your reply. This is a bit embarrassing but can you explain why these 2 recent examples of yours admit a time-function but the quotient space example you gave earlier does not admit a time-function? I don't have experience of being able to prove existence or not of a time-function given a space-time and to test for global hyperbolicity. 

Comment: By definition, a time function is a monotonic function on any time-like curve. The quotient space example admits closed time-like loops. A function on a circle cannot be strictly monotonic, hence no time function exists. On the other hand, the standard time function on Minkowski space can be projected down to the two other examples to get a time function. The key difference is that the quotient space cannot be smoothly isometrically embedded into Minkowski space, and so it cannot inherit the time function on Minkowski space. 

Comment: @Willie Thanks for your reply. And how do you show that the later two of your examples are globally hyperbolic? (Only test I know of this if I am given a metric and to check whether there exists a basis in which it can be written as a regularly sliced one) Are there purely topological methods to check global hyperbolicity? 

Comment: @Willie Now I realize why your quotient space example confused me initially. Going by the definition of "time-function" as in Yvonne's book it does not ask for monotonicity. It only asks for the gradient of the function to be time-like and its level sets to be space-like. But monotonicity does seem to be a natural demand to make to prevent space-times with closed time-like curves from having a time-function. 

Comment: No offence meant, but dude, you need to think harder about the things you read. If you have a continuously differentiable function such that its gradient never vanishes, then it must be monotonic over any $C^1$ curve transversal to the level sets...

Comment: Sorry! Should have seen that! This is high-school stuff! I am very sorry. 